# Rails partial for array item not handling object data

Tags: ruby-on-rails, renderpartial

the following view

```
<% @packageoffers.each do |packageoffer| %>
  <% if @packageoffers_mss.include?(packageoffer) %>
  <% elsif @availables.include?(packageoffer) %>
    <%= render 'packageoffer', collection: @packageoffers %>
```

is returning an NameError `undefined local variable or method 'packageoffer'` when trying to process the partial `_packageoffer.html.erb`  upon a line like the second taht follows:

```
<% item_sale_price = @item_price.sale_price * params[:quantity].to_i %>
<% markup_price = ((item_sale_price + (packageoffer.price * @r * @q)) * (1 + (@user.markup.to_d / 100) ) )  %>
```

note: @item_price is itself an item of an array `section` and had to be declared as an instance variable to pass it along `<% @item_price  = @allotments.select{ |a| a.section_id == section.id }.first`

Thus, notwithstanding following the [rails documentation](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/layouts_and_rendering.html#rendering-collections) guidelines, 
I cannot process the array's item.  Where lies the mistake?

Comment: Try `<%= render partial: 'packageoffer', collection: @packageoffers %>` or just `<%= render @packageoffers %>`

Comment: Waiter, bring me a second FULL pie of that humble stuff you got.  The guideline does state `render partial: `  The rote of calling `render 'partial'` is strong...

Comment: You mean that worked?

Comment: It seems like you're trying to render the entire collection, inside a loop over the collection. That means you'll render the whole collection many times. Are you trying to do that? Or do you just mean to render the collection once, with some items left out? If the later, you want `<%= render packageoffer %>`.

Comment: yes @Pavan.  that worked!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're using collection rendering incorrectly.

Your line...

```
<%= render 'packageoffer', collection: @packageoffers %>
```

Renders a single partial, and passes a **local variable** called `collection` with a value of `@packageoffers`.

The line you've written is a shorthand for:

```
<%= render partial: 'packageoffer', locals: { collection: @packageoffers } %>
```

If you want to render the entire collection and provide a partial name, you cannot use the render shorthand, you must use the explicit version of `render partial:...`:

```
<%= render partial: 'packageoffer', collection: @packageoffers %>
```

---

That said, it seems like your intent is to iterate over the collection, and conditionally render some items from it. In this case, you should not be using collection rendering at all, you should just use `<%= render packageoffer %>` to allow Rails to render the singular `_packageoffer` partial for each record.

Comment: I was writing an answer and looked at yours,realized I was explaining *why it didn't worked* wrongly, aborted my answer.

Comment: I never would've gotten to that shorthand interpretation. While irrelevant to the question at hand, the longhand does lead to a different result (I believe, not certain given iterations of changes).

Answer (score -1):

Is the model called Packageoffer or PackageOffer? I think your problem is that Rails tries to infer the name of the variable from the model name. Can you try if there's a `packge_offer`?

If the model is PackageOffer, then you should use `_package_offer` as the partial name, `package_offer` as the variable name and also `@package_offers`. To be consistent with Rails conventions.

EDIT: if that's the problem, you can use your code with an `as: :packageoffer` option on the render to tell rails the name to use

Comment: useful thought regarding rails conventions.  Admittedly I like the german language approach of hooking up wagons to make up a singular train with a specific meaning... and I tend to use that (the underscores are visually easier to digest, but the camelCasing on the class bothers me more - my set of rails, pun intended!).  The class here was Packageoffer .